# Does equality of Laplacians imply Kähler?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, complex-geometry, complex-manifolds, kahler-manifolds

This question follows on from [this one](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/21315/non-kahler-manifolds-where-the-different-laplacians-are-compatible).

Let $(X, \omega)$ be a Hermitian manifold and define the Laplacians $\Delta_{\partial} = \partial\partial^* + \partial^*\partial$ and $\Delta_{\bar{\partial}} = \bar{\partial}\bar{\partial}^* + \bar{\partial}^*\bar{\partial}$.

If $(X, \omega)$ is a Kähler manifold, that is $d\omega = 0$ (or equivalently $\partial\omega = 0$ or $\bar{\partial}\omega = 0$), we have $\Delta_{\bar{\partial}} = \Delta_{\partial}$.

More generally, on any Hermitian manifold we have $\Delta_{\bar{\partial}} = \Delta_{\partial} + [\partial, [\Lambda_{\partial\omega}, L]] - [\bar{\partial}, [\Lambda_{\bar{\partial}\omega}, L]]$ where:

- $[\bullet, \bullet]$ is the graded commutator;
- $\Lambda_{\partial\omega}$ and $\Lambda_{\bar{\partial}\omega}$ are the adjoints of wedging with the forms $\partial\omega$ and $\bar{\partial}\omega$ respectively; and
- $L$ is the Lefschetz operator, that is, wedging with $\omega$.

It is clear how the additional terms relating the Laplacians in the Hermitian case vanish if the metric is Kähler ($\partial\omega = 0$ and $\bar{\partial}\omega = 0$, so $\Lambda_{\partial\omega}$ and $\Lambda_{\bar{\partial}\omega}$ are both zero). What about the converse? That is:

> If $\Delta_{\bar{\partial}} = \Delta_{\partial}$ on a Hermitian manifold $(X, \omega)$, is it necessarily Kähler?

---

The accepted answer in the linked question refers to *balanced* manifolds. These are manifolds with the property that $\Delta_{\bar{\partial}}f = \Delta_{\partial}f$ for any smooth *function* $f$. Not all such manifolds are Kähler. The above question is stronger as it requires equality for all smooth *forms*.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The answer is yes, as proved by Y. Ogawa in [this paper,](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.jdg/1214429279) see Theorem 3.10. Apparently equality on functions and $1$-forms is enough to conclude that the metric is Kähler.

There is also a [related paper by C.C.Hsiung](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9947-1966-0189067-0), see Theorem 4.2.

Comment: Thanks YangMills. I have only had a brief look these papers, but it is not immediately clear to me that they answer my question. I'm sure they do, I just want to be certain before I accept your answer. My main point of unease is in Theorem 3.10 of Ogawa's paper which states that if the operator $\square$ (which I believe is $\Delta_{\bar{\partial}}$ in the above notation) is real for all 0 and 1 forms, then the (almost) Hermitian structure is Kähler. As $\Delta_{\partial}$ is real, we just need the remaining terms $\dots$

Comment: $\dots [\partial, [\Lambda_{\partial\omega}, L]] - [\bar{\partial}, [\Lambda_{\bar{\partial}\omega}, L]]$ to be real. With this in mind, we have the following:
$$\overline{[\partial, [\Lambda_{\partial\omega}, L]] - [\bar{\partial}, [\Lambda_{\bar{\partial}\omega}, L]]} = [\bar{\partial}, [\Lambda_{\bar{\partial}\omega}, L]] - [\partial, [\Lambda_{\partial\omega}, L]] = -([\partial, [\Lambda_{\partial\omega}, L]] - [\bar{\partial}, [\Lambda_{\bar{\partial}\omega}, L]]).$$
Does this show that $\Delta_{\bar{\partial}}$ is real iff $\Delta_{\bar{\partial}} = \Delta_{\partial}$?

Comment: Yes, indeed in general you have that $\overline{\Delta_{\overline{\partial}}}=\Delta_{\partial}$, so the two Laplacians are equal iff any one of them is a real operator. 

Another way to see this is to note that your calculation shows that the error term is a purely imaginary operator.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I was thinking, but I just wanted to make sure.

Comment: As the papers are using almost Hermitian metrics, the relationship between $\Delta_{\partial}$ and $\Delta_{\bar{\partial}}$ would have additional terms. However, a similar argument must hold to show that the entire error term (as YangMills calls it) is a purely imaginary operator.

Comment: Yes, I thought your question was for integrable complex structure. But you're right, those two papers prove something for non-integrable almost-complex structures as well, but you have to be careful of what their "Laplacians" are in that case.

Comment: My question was for integrable complex structures, I was just remarking that in the case of almost Hermitian metrics, which is the context of both papers, the relationship between the Laplacians will not be the one I had in my question. Having said that, your comment seems to suggest that there are issues with relating (or maybe even defining) the Laplacians in this case. What is the problem? $\partial$ and $\bar{\partial}$ are still defined and so are $\partial^*$ and $\bar{\partial}^*$, aren't they?

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the papers mentioned by YangMills, there is also the [earlier paper](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?pg1=MR&s1=0205205&loc=fromreflist) by A. W. Adler which shows that if $\Delta = 2\Delta_{\bar{\partial}}$ on a hermitian manifold, then it is Kähler.